# Multiple Files merge based on file1 keys

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

I was trying to achieve merging of multiple files with main file keys.
 My main file is like this

> cat files.txt

Which has keys, want to compare....

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
```

Other inputs files like this

> cat f1.txt

```
1 : 20
3 : 40
5 : 40
7 : 203
```

> cat f2.txt

```
3 : 45
4 : 56
9 : 23
```

Want output like this ..

```
   f1 f2 ....
1  20 NA
2  NA NA
3  40 45
4  56 NA
5  40 NA
6  NA NA
7  203 NA
8  NA NA
9  23 NA
10 NA NA
11 NA NA
```

tried this but not able to print the non-match keys

```
awk -F':' 'NF>1{a[$1] = a[$1]$2}END{for(i in a){print i""a[i]}}' files.txt *.txt
1  20
3  40 45
4  56
5  40
7  203
9  23
```

Please can someone guide me what is missing here ?

Comment: Thanks William for correcting the question

Comment: Do you **REALLY** want some of the values from `f2.txt` to appear under the `f1` output column? If so - why are the output column names the same as your input file names, are they not related? If so in what way, if not then you really threw several of us by giving them the same names!

Comment: @ASRRAJ, correct your expected output to avoid confusing

Answer (score 1):

Complex GNU ***awk*** solution (will cover any number of files, considering system resources):

```
awk 'BEGIN{ 
         PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"; h="  "; 
         for(i=2;i<=ARGC;i++) h=(i==2)? h ARGV[i]: h OFS ARGV[i]; print h 
     }
     NR==FNR{ a[$1]; next }{ b[ARGIND][$1]=$3 }
     END{ 
         for(i in a) { 
             printf("%d",i); 
             for(j in b) printf("%s%s",OFS,(i in b[j])? b[j][i] : "NA"); print "" 
         } 
     }' files.txt *.txt
```

An exemplary output:

```
  f1 f2 
1 20 NA
2 NA NA
3 40 45
4 NA 56
5 40 NA
6 NA NA
7 203 NA
8 NA NA
9 NA 23
10 NA NA
11 NA NA
```

---

- `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"` - sorting mode (numerically in ascending order)
- `for(i=2;i<=ARGC;i++) h=(i==1)? h ARGV[i]: h OFS ARGV[i]` - iterating through script arguments, collecting filenames. 
  `ARGC` and `ARGV` make the command-line arguments available to your program

Comment: Nice 1. (gave up, this is a filler)

Comment: Giving error awk: cmd. line:4:      NR==FNR{ a[$1]; next }{ b[ARGIND][$1]=$3 }
awk: cmd. line:4:                                       ^ syntax error

Comment: @ASRRAJ, I suppose, you have improperly copy/pasted my code. Make another try

Comment: @ RomanPerekhrest 55  Looks like i m not able to get it still facing issue to execute this, as  new to awk not sure where i am missing ??

Comment: I suspect ASR isn't using GNU awk so his awk is choking on the gawk-specific multi-dimensional array syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat awk-file
NR==FNR{
  l=NR
  next
}
NR==FNR+l{
  split(FILENAME,f1,".")
  a[$1]=$3 
  next
}
NR==FNR+l+length(a){
  split(FILENAME,f2,".")
  bwk -v OFS='\t' -f awk-file files.txt f1.txt f2.txt[$1]=$3                                                                                                                                                 
  next
}
END{
  print "",f1[1],f2[1]
  for(i=1;i<=l;i++){
    print i,(a[i]!="")?a[i]:"NR",(b[i]!="")?b[i]:"NR"
  }
}
$ awk -v OFS='\t' -f awk-file files.txt f1.txt f2.txt 
        f1      f2
1       20      NR
2       NR      NR
3       40      45
4       NR      56
5       40      NR
6       NR      NR
7       203     NR
8       NR      NR
9       NR      23
10      NR      NR
11      NR      NR
```

I modify the answer for your further question.
If you have 3rd, 4th files (assume to nth files), add n new blocks as followed,

```
NR==FNR+l+length(a)+...+length(n){
  split(FILENAME,fn,".")
  n[$1]=$3
}
```

And in your `End` block,

```
END{
  print "",f1[1],f2[1],...,fn[1]
  for(i=1;i<=l;i++){
    print i,(a[i]!="")?a[i]:"NR",(b[i]!="")?b[i]:"NR",...,(n[i]!="")?n[i]:"NR"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but i need this input for multiple files say i have 100 + files like f1,f2,f3,f4, etc etc ....

Comment: Never use the letter `l` as a variable name as it looks far too much like the number `1` and so obfuscates your code.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk and `sort -n` for sorting the output:

```
$ awk -F" *: *" '
NR==FNR {
    a[$1]; next }
FNR==1 {
    for(i in a)
        a[i]=a[i] " NA"
    h=h OFS FILENAME
}
{
    match(a[$1]," NA")
    a[$1]=substr(a[$1],1,RSTART-1) OFS $2 substr(a[$1],RSTART+RLENGTH)
} 
END { 
    print h
    for(i in a) 
        print i a[i]
}' files f1 f2 |sort -n
 f1 f2
1 20 NA
2 NA NA
3 40 45
4 56 NA
5 40 NA
6 NA NA
7 203 NA
8 NA NA
9 23 NA
10 NA NA
11 NA NA
```

Pitfalls: 1. `sort` will fail with the header in certain situations. 2. Since `NA` is replaced with the value `$2`, your data can't have `NA` starting strings. That could probably be circumvented with replacing `/ NA( |$)/` but would probably cause a lot more checking in the code, so choose your `NA` carefully. :D

**Edit**:

Running it for, for example, four files:

```
$ awk '...' files f1 f2 f1 f2 | sort -n
1 20 20 NA NA
2 NA NA NA NA
3 40 45 40 45
4 56 56 NA NA
5 40 40 NA NA
6 NA NA NA NA
7 203 203 NA NA
8 NA NA NA NA
9 23 23 NA NA
10 NA NA NA NA
11 NA NA NA NA
```

Comment: @ASRRAJ Please see my edit. At least for the data you provided it seems to work. Please provide a non-working sample for debugging (don't post it as comment, edit it to your OP), thank you,

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
ARGIND < (ARGC-1) { map[ARGIND,$1] = $NF; next }
FNR==1 {
    printf "%-2s", ""
    for (fileNr=1; fileNr<ARGIND; fileNr++) {
        fileName = ARGV[fileNr]
        sub(/\.txt$/,"",fileName)
        printf "%s%s", OFS, fileName
    }
    print ""
}
{
    printf "%-2s", $1
    for (fileNr=1; fileNr<ARGIND; fileNr++) {
        printf "%s%s", OFS, ((fileNr,$1) in map ? map[fileNr,$1] : "NA")
    }
    print ""
}

$ awk -f tst.awk f1.txt f2.txt files.txt
   f1 f2
1  20 NA
2  NA NA
3  40 45
4  NA 56
5  40 NA
6  NA NA
7  203 NA
8  NA NA
9  NA 23
10 NA NA
11 NA NA
```

The above uses GNU awk for ARGIND, with other awks just add a line `FNR==1{ARGIND++}` at the start of the script.

Comment: Actually, the `f2` values in OP's expected output are also in the first column (56 and 23). They seem to be piling or starting from the index column.

Comment: Well so they are - apparently I and several others misunderstood the question. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Please use the below script to process.
FILESPATH has the list of your input files (f1.txt, f2.txt...).
INPUT has the input file (files.txt).

## script.sh

```
FILESPATH=/home/ubuntu/work/test/
INPUT=/home/ubuntu/work/files.txt
i=0
while read line
do
    FILES[ $i ]="$line"
    (( i++ ))
done < <(ls $FILESPATH/*.txt)

for file in  "${FILES[@]}"
do
    echo -n "  ${file##*/}"
done
echo ""

while IFS= read -r var
do
    echo -n "$var " 
    for file in "${FILES[@]}"
    do
        VALUE=`grep "$var " $file | cut -d ' ' -f3`
        if [ ! -z $VALUE ]; then
            echo -n "$VALUE    "
        else
            echo -n "NA    "
        fi
    done
    echo ""

done < "$INPUT"
```

========
you can use printf instead of echo to get better formatting of output.

Comment: Not as buggy as the other shell loop solution but still has issues and will be very slow, see  [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for some of the issues then google parsing ls, all upper case variable names, deprecated backticks, for some of the others.

Answer (score -1):

This can be done via simple loop and echo statements.

```
#!/bin/bash
NA=" NA"
i=0

#print header module start

header[i]=" "
for file in `ls f[0-9].txt`;
do
first_part=`echo $file|cut -d. -f1`
i=$i+1
header[i]=$first_part
done
echo ${header[@]}

#print header module end


#print elements start
for element in `cat files.txt`;
do

 var=$element
        for file in `ls f[0-9].txt`;
        do
                var1=`grep -w ${element} $file`
                 if [[ ! -z $var1 ]] ; then
                 field2=`echo $var1|cut -d":" -f2`
                 var="$var$field2"
                 else
                 var="$var$NA"
                 fi
        done
                 echo $var

done
#print elements end
```

Comment: Thanks!!! Nice one only thing first column is not having any header so filename need to start from second columns.

Comment: That is riddled with bugs and will be immensely slow. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for a few of the issues - there's too many to list.